# URL Images not playing videos with Augmented Reality (AR) Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I am implementing a bring Images to life feature, this is the [blog](https://medium.com/krootl/arcore-sceneform-simple-video-playback-3fe2f909bfbc) that I was following, and I tried to convert the URL image to bitmap but it seems not connecting to a local video.

I am using Picasso, to download the image as a bitmap from a URL but it can't seem to be working.

Below is my code :

```
override fun getSessionConfiguration(session: Session): Config {

        fun loadAugmentedImageBitmap(imageName: String): Bitmap =
            requireContext().assets.open(imageName).use { return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it) }

        val loader = activity?.applicationContext?.let { Coil.imageLoader(it) }


        var hashMap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>()

        hashMap.put(
            TEST_VIDEO_1,
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/do6g6dwlz/image/upload/v1594037658/lofsos15kot28ymz9fwb.jpg"
        )
        hashMap.put(
            TEST_VIDEO_2,
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/do6g6dwlz/image/upload/v1594038114/ijl9ngoomay9mleifv88.jpg"
        )
        hashMap.put(
            TEST_VIDEO_3,
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/do6g6dwlz/image/upload/v1594038131/po2fp4mviqsqkvwpztpe.jpg"
        )

        fun setupAugmentedImageDatabase(config: Config, session: Session): Boolean {
            try {
                config.augmentedImageDatabase = AugmentedImageDatabase(session).also { db ->


                    for ((key, value) in hashMap) {

                        print("load URL ---- $value")

                        Picasso.get().load(value).into(object : com.squareup.picasso.Target {
                            override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Loading Images",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }

                            override fun onBitmapFailed(
                                e: java.lang.Exception?,
                                errorDrawable: Drawable?
                            ) {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Something wrong happened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }

                            override fun onBitmapLoaded(
                                bitmap: Bitmap?,
                                from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?
                            ) {
                                db.addImage(key, bitmap)
                            }

                        })
                    }
                }
                return true
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not add bitmap to augmented image database", e)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IO exception loading augmented image bitmap.", e)
            }
            return false
        }

        return super.getSessionConfiguration(session).also {
            it.lightEstimationMode = Config.LightEstimationMode.DISABLED
            it.focusMode = Config.FocusMode.AUTO

            if (!setupAugmentedImageDatabase(it, session)) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "Could not setup augmented image database",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
      

  }
    }
```

This is the entire [class](https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/d711143028b7d090fe3ee274cec764a3) and as well as the repository [link](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/ARHuxy)

**NOTE:**

When both the Images and Videos are in the local project, it works fine, but trying to access both via URL  it doesn't work.

Comment: did u solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
try {
                hasmap.map { 
                    addImage(key, convertURLtoBitmap(your_URL(value)), 0.5f)
                    Log.e(TAG, "bitmap added SuccessFully")
                }
```

for convertURLtoBitmap

```
private fun convertURLtoBitmap(your_url: String?): Bitmap? {
  
    return Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
        .load(your_url)
        .submit()
        .get()
}
```